# NullReferenceException when function returns

Tags: c#, weak-references

I am getting a NullReferenceException when running my multi-threaded application, but only when I run in Release mode outside of the debugger.  The stack trace gets logged, and it always points to the same function call.  I put several logging statements in the function to try to determine how far it would get, and every statement gets logged, including one on the last line of the function.  What is interesting is that when the NullReferenceException occurs, the statement after the function call does not get logged:

```
    // ...
    logger.Log( "one" );  // logged
    Update( false );
    logger.Log( "eleven" );  // not logged when exception occurs
}

private void Update( bool condition )
{
    logger.Log( "one" );  // logged
    // ...  
    logger.Log( "ten" );  // logged, even when exception occurs
}
```

The exception does not occur every time the function is called.  Is it possible that the stack is being corrupted either before or during execution of the function such that the return address is lost, resulting in the null reference?  I didn't think that sort of thing was possible under .NET, but I guess stranger things have happened.

I tried replacing the call to the function with the contents of the function, so everything happens inline, and the exception then occurs on a line that looks like this:

```
foreach ( ClassItem item in classItemCollection )
```

I have verified through logging that the "classItemCollection" is not null, and I also tried changing the foreach to a for in case the IEnumerator was doing something funny, but the exception occurs on the same line.

Any ideas on how to investigate this further?

**Update:** Several responders have suggested possible solutions having to do with making sure the logger isn't null.  To be clear, the logging statements were added for debugging purposes after the exception started happening.

Comment: Can include the code of the function here? Might make it easier to spot what is happening.

Comment: > "...Is it possible that the stack is being corrupted...?" < In C#?, no; for all practical purposes that's impossible. Unless you are calling unsafe code.

Comment: re "eleven" not being logged - perhaps it just isn't being flushed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my null reference.  Like Fredrik and micahtan suggested, I didn't provide enough information for the community to find a solution, so I figured I should post what I found just to put this to rest.

This is a representation of what was happening:

```
ISomething something = null;

//...

// the Add method returns a strong reference to an ISomething
// that it creates.  m_object holds a weak reference, so when
// "this" no longer has a strong reference, the ISomething can
// be garbage collected.
something = m_object.Add( index );

// the Update method looks at the ISomethings held by m_object.
// it obtains strong references to any that have been added,
// and puts them in m_collection;
Update( false );

// m_collection should hold the strong reference created by 
// the Update method.
// the null reference exception occurred here
something = m_collection[ index ];

return something;
```

The problem turned out to be my use of the "something" variable as a temporary strong reference until the Update method obtained a permanent one.  The compiler, in Release mode, optimizes away the "something = m_object.Add();" assignment, since "something" isn't used until it is assigned again.  This allowed the ISomething to be garbage collected, so it no longer existed in m_collection when I tried to access it.

All I had to do was ensure that I held a strong reference until after the call to Update.

I am doubtful that this will be of any use to anyone, but in case anyone was curious, I didn't want to leave this question unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it logs "ten" would make me look first at:

- is `logger` ever assigned... is this perhaps becoming null somehow
- is the bug inside `Log` itself

Hard to tell without enough context for either - but that is how I'd investigate it. You could also add a simple `null` test somewhere; as a cheeky approach, you could rename the `Log` method to something else, and add an extension method:

```
[Conditional("TRACE")]
public static void Log(this YourLoggerType logger, string message) {
    if(logger==null) {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("logger",
            "logger was null, logging " + message);
    } else {
       try {
           logger.LogCore(message); // the old method
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "logger failed, logging " + message, ex);
       }
    }
}
```

Your existing code should call the new `Log` extension method, and the exception will make it clear exactly where it barfed. Maybe change it back once fixed... or maybe leave it.

Comment: I added the logging calls after the exception started showing up to try to figure out what was happening.  Certain placements of logging statements seem to make the problem go away, which seems to suggest this is related to timing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you modifying classItemCollection from multiple threads?  If you change the collection in another thread you may be invalidating the iterator which might lead to your exception.  You may need to protect access with a lock.

edit:
Can you post more info about the types of ClassItem and classItemCollection?

Another possibility is that ClassItem is a value type and classItemCollection is a generic collection and somehow a null is getting added to the collection. The following throws a NullReferenceException:

```
        ArrayList list=new ArrayList();

        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);
        list.Add(null);
        list.Add(4);

        foreach (int i in list)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

This particular problem can be resolved by int? i or Object i in the foreach or using a generic container.

Comment: classItemCollection is local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Agree w/Fredrik -- more details are necessary.  One place to maybe start looking: you mention multi-threaded application and the error happening in release but not debug.  You might be running into a timing issue with multiple threads accessing the same object references.

Regardless, I'd also probably put a:

```
Debug.Assert(classItemCollection != null);
```

right before the loop iteration.  It won't help you in release mode, but it may help you catch the problem if (when?) it happens in Debug.

Comment: I put in an "if ( classItemCollection != null )" around the foreach, and the exception still occurs.  It really isn't possible for this collection to be null.  It can be empty, but not null.

Comment: If the collection isn't null, I'm not sure why you'd be getting a NRE on that line of code.  I'm curious as to what the problem is...  (is it bad if you *want* to debug things like this?)

Answer (score 0):

I'd look for code that's setting logger or one of its dependents to null.  Are there properties of logger that, when set to null, might trigger this?  Release mode sometimes speeds up application execution which can reveal synchronization problems that are masked by the performance penalty of debug mode and/or the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that "eleven" isn't getting logged leads me to believe that logger is being set to null just before that call is made. Can you wrap it in a try/catch and see if it hits the catch portion of the block? Maybe you can insert a MessageBox.Show or write something to a known file when that happens.